# Next js how to render item array with the same name as an import

Tags: arrays, next.js, render

I'm tryed render item array with the same name as an import without success, as per the code below.
Does anyone have an idea? thanks!

This test does not work.

```js
import _01 from './components/01.js' 
import _02 from './components/02.js' 
import _03 from './components/03.js'

export default function xpto(){ 
    const myArray = [{Comp:'_01'},{Comp:'_02'},{Comp:'_03'}]

    return (
        <div>
            {myArray.map((Comp, index)=>{
                <div key={index}>
                    <${Comp} /> {/*this would be solved with a simple macro substitution, how to do?*/}
                </div>
            })}
       </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your arrow function passed as parameter to `map`. If you use brackets, it's almost like a normal `function`, so you have to do a return statement.

```js
myArray.map((Comp, index)=>{
  return (
    <div key={index}>
      <${Comp}/>
    </div>
  );
});
```

If your function is a single statement, you can remove the brackets. If it would just be a return statement, you can omit the `return` keyword.

```js
myArray.map((Comp, index)=>
  <div key={index}>
    <${Comp}/>
  </div>
);
```

Besides, if you print `Comp` there, you'll get the entire object, like `{Comp: '01'}`, so you probably want to print `Comp.Comp` inside `map`.

So the problem's doesn't have anything to do with the imports or with Next.js.